# Wallpaper not updating (Loki)

Tags: release-loki, wallpaper

The wallpaper doesn't change when I set the wallpaper
I have tried in System Settings or by the command line `set-wallpaper`

When I go to "Multitasking view" the new wallpaper does show but switches back to the old one when I am in normal view.

If I log out and log back in, it does update.

Answer (score 4):

You have to restart or at least reload `gala` to change the wallpaper, for exemple you can type in a terminal window:

```
killall -HUP gala
```

This might be related to a bug as well…

Comment: Or open the Applications menu and type `gala -r`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a [known issue](https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/13) in Gala. The problem seems to be triggered by plugging in a new display.

The [workaround](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10124/792) posted by lemonslice resolves the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what I changed, but this started working.  I have been altering the NVIDIA settings, so that may have something to do with it.

Anyway, it's working as expected now without having to restart gala.
I'll report again if I find what the bug was

Answer (score -2):

If you have an Intel; run this in the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-intel
sudo apt autoremove
```

and reboot your system.

Comment: This uh...

Yeah... I would not try this

Do the video drivers magically reinstall themselves?

Comment: You guys are talking crap to that poster, but His fix worked instantly for me. Be aware that I'm running ElementaryOS `Juno`, inside a VMware Workstation Pro 15 VM. However that fix worked across reboots as well. This is what worked: `sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-intel; sudo apt autoremove`