# Switching wallpapers doesn't work on Juno

Tags: release-juno, wallpaper

For some reason, in order to switch my wallpaper, I need to reboot my pc every time, and if I am not doing that, it will just mark the wallpaper I chose as "selected", but won't actually change until I reboot.

Is there any solution to that?

Comment: Same here... Workaround: logout - login

Comment: Also a problem for myself. And having to logout and back in is not a tenable fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same problem was [solved for Loki previously](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10124/100).

You have to restart (or at least reload) Gala to change the wallpaper. To do that, you can type or paste the following into Terminal:

`killall -HUP gala`

The `-HUP` flag tells the command to basically "Hang-UP" the gala process, which makes it restart.